# Web Api - Really slow response when performing few requests at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API C# project. I noticed that when sending few requests together (few can be even 7-10) to the controller, some of the requests are taking very long time (5-7 seconds).  When sending each request separately, each request takes less than 200ms.  I'm sending requests to my localhost (dev environment), so there shouldn't be any latency or heavy usage on the server.

I added this code inside global.asax in order to view how long it takes for each request.

```js
//Global asax

 private Dictionary<string, StopWatch> urlTimers = new Dictionary<string, StopWatch>();
    void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContextBase currentContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        var requestedUrl = currentContext.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
        var urlWithoutQueryParams = requestedUrl.Split('?')[0];
        if (urlWithoutQueryParams.StartsWith("/controller"))
        {
            var stopWatch = new StopWatch();
            stopWatch.Start(urlWithoutQueryParams);
            urlTimers[urlWithoutQueryParams] = stopWatch;
        }

     
    }

    void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContextBase currentContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        var requestedUrl = currentContext.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
        var urlWithoutQueryParams = requestedUrl.Split('?')[0];
        if (urlWithoutQueryParams.StartsWith("/controller"))
        {
            var stopWatch = urlTimers[urlWithoutQueryParams];
            if (stopWatch != null)
            {
                stopWatch.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
```

When submitting 10 requests using fiddler I receive the following

[image]

All requests return a tiny amount of data, so it also shouldn't be the problem. 
It doesn't make sense that 10 requests take so much time. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will *assume* this is not yet a MVC 6 Web Api (presence of Global.asax and all) but MVC 5 or lower. One of the things that people forget in a MVC 5 Web API is the SessionState.
A couple of short blogs on this:

- http://www.compilemode.com/2015/12/sessionstate-controller-attribute-in.html
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624883/Performance-Tip-A-few-words-on-ASP-NET-session-sta

In short it comes down to this:

With SessionState enable, only one request is processed per User session at one time. 
In your case this means:

- GetAsKeyValuePairs is processed
- then GetTranslationManagmentData is processed
- then IsCaptionsExist is processed
- ...

They are all requested at the same time, so they have the same start time. 
The end time of a request however, depends on the time needed by the previous requests + it's own processing time. This causes the increase in time per call in your sample.

If your actions do not access the Session information, you can 'safely' add the `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]` attribute on your controllers (see blogs).
That will result in the calls being processed at the same time. Just don't use this on controllers that change your session information.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You really saved me.
With [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)] can I still read the session ? If I understand correctly, now I get a clone of the session for each request?

Comment: You can still read them (even change them, but don't, not worth the problems it can bring). Look at it like this. Normal session state behavior locks the session when a requests starts and unlocks it at the end. With readonly, there is no lock. 2 calls could change the same data, so only read it. See sessionstate as a singleton within a user session.

Comment: Thank you so much. Really helped me